# how to display pop up jquery form edit in codeiginiter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm a newbie in Codeigniter, I have a problem when I click the edit button, form edit can't pop up. I don't know how to modal `popup` so that it can work properly.how to configure controller?

my controller

```
public function edit()
{
    $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->load->model('m_activity');
    $data['data']=$this->m_activity->per_id($id);

}
```

my model

```
function per_id($id)
{
    $this->db->where('activity_detail_id',$id);
    $query=$this->db->get('t_trx_activity_detail');
    return $query->result();
}
```

my view

```
<a href='<?php echo site_url();?>activity/edit/<?php echo 
                                        $row->activity_detail_id;?>'class="btn btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm purple" data-toggle="modal" >
                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit </a> |

<div class="modal fade left" id="edit">
```

Comment: You're asking about jQuery but do not include any jQuery code in the question.  If this is simply a question about how to use PHP to construct a certain URL, then this too really has nothing to do with jQuery.  Please explain better what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many jquery library are there. One of them is Jquery UI. You can use its dialog.

[Reference](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

EX:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my problem when i click edit button,where edit form have record database.not blank